# Rails custom devise sign in messages for disabled users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, devise, message

I am making a rails applications where I have users which can also be admins.
Admins can disable users. I am allowing disabled users to log in and view the content, but not post anything.

How can I create a custom message that would inform a user that his account is disabled when he logs in? Currently my default devise notice shows (Logged in successfully).

At first I solved this issue by simply disabling the user to log in like this:

user.rb

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && self.is_active?
  end

  def inactive_message
    is_active? ? super : 'Your account has been disabled. Please contact our support team if you think this was a mistake.'
  end
```

But like this the user cannot log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your disabled users are not really "disabled", I would recommend to assign them instead a "readonly" role, and tailor the authorizations accordingly. The cancan gem https://github.com/ryanb/cancan makes this very easy and is well integrated with devise.

In this way you can also preserve the true disabling function, which you may need later.

Comment: I already implemented the functionality so the users are "readonly" now I only need to add the flash message on login.

Comment: Oops, that was not very clear. you can just put a line in the controller action rendering the home page e.g.: 
    flash[:notify] =  "Note: Read-only Access"
and make room for it in the page layout:
                <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                <%= content_tag :span, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
            <% end %>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add this to the devise session controller? Because right now that devise controller is taking care of everything and I can't seem to find the access to it.

Comment: Devise doc on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise has a section on Configuring Controllers explaining how to extend it.